# Why does infinite union represent at least one occurring?

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

Why in probability does multiple union of events represent AT LEAST one occurring?

Comment: What would you expect it to mean?

Comment: Compare with finite union: $A\cup B\cup C$ means that one pr more of $A,B,C$ occur (in other words, at least one of $A,B,C$ occurs)

Answer (score 3):

Consider a fair, six-sided die. Let $X$ be the event "an odd number is rolled," and let $Y$ be the event "a number $<5$ is rolled." That is, $X=\{1, 3, 5\}$ and $Y=\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$.

Then $X\cup Y=\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$. Note that this includes cases where $X$ holds and $Y$ doesn't ($5$), cases where $Y$ holds and $X$ doesn't ($2$ and $4$), and cases where both $X$ and $Y$ hold ($1$ and $3$).

So it should be clear that a union of *two* events represents the event "either one happens, or the other happens, or they both happen" - that is, "at least one happens."

The picture is the same with three events, four events, or any number of events: the union is the set of outcomes that make *any* event happen, including more than one event; so the union represents "at least one of the events happens."